Is the second fundamental form of an embedding submanifold on $\mathbb{R}^d$ always bounded? any proof or counterexample?
Let $M$ be an embedding submanifold in Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $i:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^d$ is the embedding map. We can give the pullback metric $g_M = i^{\ast}(g_E)$ to $M$ to make it as a Riemannian submanifold, where $g_E$ is the standard Euclidean metric.
My question is: is the second fundamental form of $(M, g_M)$ always bounded? We can assume that $M$ is compact and smooth enough.
At first, I think it is right, because the second fundamental form is some matrix functions on $M$, it is the projection of the variance of normal vector fields of $M$ along the tangent space, I think it should be good if $M$ is smooth enough... . However, the second fundamental form of the sphere with radius $R$ is $1/R$, if I glue some small balls to a smooth submanifold with radius $R$ smaller and smaller, what will happen?
So far I don't find any reference about this question, anyone can give me some hint about the proof or counterexamples? Thanks very very much!

Hint: A continuous function on a compact topological space is necessarily bounded.

@Moishe Kohan hi, I think this is the key point. Any possibility that second fundamental form is not continuous? How can I prove it using local coordinates ?

Start by writing down the definition of the 2nd fundamental form using local coordinates.

Is your submanifold $C^2$?

@Ted Shifrin Yes, we can assume that the submanifold is smooth.

Then how are you gluing balls to a smooth submanifold? Anyhow, the second fundamental form of a smooth submanifold is smooth.

@Ted Shifrin Any proof to show "the second fundamental form of a smooth submanifold is smooth"? I don't think it is trivial. You mean that its normal bundle is also smooth? then...

Of course the normal bundle is smooth. This is a standard elementary result. See Guillemin and Pollack, for example.

Did you try the suggestion of Mishe Kohan? Do you have a formula for the second fundamental form in local coordinates?

@Arctic Char Yes, I've try to write down the formula in local coordinates. This is my steps: 1. I can write down k tangent vector fields of $M$ using coordinate functions of $M$, 2. I solve the linear equation group, their coefficients are these tangent vector fields, 3. Then I can obtain d-k normal vector fields, and I take derivative of these normal vector fields to reach the second fundamental form. But there still has some trouble. In the second step, I need division when I solve the linear equation group, then I can't make sure everything is good after I taking derivative.

@Arctic Char, I think Ted Shifrin is right, I find this question, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712986/normal-bundle-of-a-manifold Maybe I should start from the normal bundle to compute the second fundamental form instead of $M$.

Consider the following 1-dimensional example : a spiral rotating to the origin in the plane, for instance the so called logarithmic spiral $\rho = \exp \theta$. The curvature must go to infinity when $\rho $ goes to $0$.

@Thomas, I think it is a very good example... But How can I understand the point $0$, is it still a submanifold near $0$?

0 does not belong to this set.

@Thomas But OP said to assume  $M$ is compact and "smooth enough."

@Thomas Yes, It is not compact if $0$ does not belong to that set. Maybe we can redesign the example based on logarithmic spiral.

If your manifold is not $C^2$, but only 2-times derivable, you can construct  very wild examples in the plane : if you consider the curve $y=f(x)$ where $f$ is twice differentiable, then its curvature is $\kappa = { f"(x)\over (1+f'^2(x))^{3/2}}$.  So you can produce examples where the curvature is not bounded in the neigbourhood of every point..

@Thomas Even $f(x)$ is not $C^2$ function, its graph could be C^2 manifold, for example $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$.
